# Print Aligned Data Txt Python

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a dataframe with 2-decimal values and I have to print it into a txt file in a way that the points (".") of the numbers are located in the same position in every row, no matter the size of the number, and also in every column as the example:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: It looks like simply printing the dataframe (without the index) would work since Pandas already aligns numbers like that, so I've closed your question accordingly. If that's not quite right, please make a [minimal reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).